# Action Bar Sherlock and Button Text Color

Tags: android, button, actionbarsherlock, textcolor

I've implemented Action Bar Sherlock in one of my apps, and cannot figure out why the text in my buttons shows up in white when I haven't set it to any color. I would like for it to remain the default black color, but even when I add this color attribute into the layout file, the button text color remains white. Any ideas on what might be wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default theme for ABS includes white text. To change the theme, look at this :

[Using ActionBarSherlock without the default Android theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14167794/using-actionbarsherlock-without-the-default-android-theme)

Comment: I remember finding the list of themes within ABS; are you saying that there is a theme that would allow colored text?

Comment: Yes (though I haven't tried it myself): http://actionbarsherlock.com/theming.html